# Issues debugging copy paste unique values

Tags: vba, excel, unique

I am having issues debugging some code I've been working on to copy Unique values from Column AD from Worksheets(1). For the line

```
aRange.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Worksheets(2).Range("A1"), Unique:=True
```

I keep getting the debugging error:

> The extract range has a missing or illegal field name.

What am I missing?

```
Sub FilteroOutUniquesSerialNumber()

Dim uniquesArray As Variant
Dim LastRow As Variant
Dim aRange As Range
Set aRange = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Columns("AD:AD")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With Worksheets(2)
    aRange.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Worksheets(2).Range("A1"), Unique:=True
    LastRow = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(.Rows.Count, "AD").End(xlUp).Row
    uniquesArray = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("AD2:AD" & LastRow)
End With
Dim txt As String, i As Integer
For i = 1 To UBound(uniquesArray)
    txt = txt & uniquesArray(i, 1) & ","
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a header in AD1 ?

Comment: Yes there typically is. In my current form I'm testing there isn't, but 99% of the time there will be. I originally wanted to just copy/paste and then filter out Uniques. But sometimes Column AD will have up to 500,000 rows, and the Filter out Uniques only goes to the standard 76,XXX as far as I can tell.

Comment: Doesn't work for me if there's no header...

Comment: You're saying my code above works for you if a header is present?

Comment: I'd love to allow the suggestion, but I don't have enogh rep to do so.

Comment: My bad - I tested a shorted version and it gave me an error when there was no header, but testing your full version does not...  If there's no header, then no data gets copied.

Comment: Not sure why I'm getting an error regardless... something else must be goin' on.

Comment: Part of the advanced filter operation creates a named range called "Extract" in the workbook, which points to the destination for the unique list.  You may have a corrupted version, so try deleting that and see if it fixes things.

Comment: The issue is probably what you've mentioned here. I know that this same code has been working for me in the past. I'll see what I can come up with. P.S. what would allow this macro to work even if there are headers?

Answer (score 0):

There is always another way to do things. You could always creat another sheet, copy the data you need, and use RemoveDuplicates Excel Formula, which I think is more efficient, you might import this code into yours:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Columns("AD:AD").Copy
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(3).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(3).CurrentRegion.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
uniquesArray = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(3).CurrentRegion
```

You can always delet content or whole sheet after performing such task.